# How setup and access underlying ID's in selected Rows in a wpf DataTemplated ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I've populated a wpf ListBox using a DataTemplate in xaml and a System.Data.DataSet in the vb.net code behind. I've sneeked in a underlying numeric database ID in a DockPanel ToolTip of the DataTemplate. My question: Is there a simple way to reference these IDs in the Click event of the ListBox? I wish to store and act upon multiple selected IDs without hard coding specific Classes or ObservableCollections. In VB6 I would have simply stored the IDs in the ItemData property of a ListBox.

Comment: Don't use `System.Data` to bind to WPF UIs. Create a proper data Model instead.

Comment: What is improper about a DataSet? The data in question exists in a database!

Comment: a `DataSet` is a really poor way to store data. It's just a glorified `Dictionary`, where you need to access things via a "magic string key" (such as `row["LastName"]` which returns an `object` which you then need to CAST to the adequate type). You should create a proper data model where data is stored in a proper, strongly typed manner. Say a `Person` class with a `public string LastName {get;set;}` property and stuff like that.

Comment: But how would the class access the database? I created a standard .net (ADO) DataSet so I can set the ListBox’s DataContext to it. With just a few lines of code I got a fancy looking ListBox with automatic virtualisation (the database table contains over 16000 records). WPF is great up to this point. The problem now is inferring which records are being referenced when multiple rows are selected in the ListBox. Note, the interface won't be modifying the database, it merely needs to pass IDs to code elsewhere that will.

Comment: See [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx). Or any other ORMs. Otherwise create a server-side logic that maps your `System.Data` stuff to proper classes. Otherwise create a proper Strongly-Typed ViewModel to sit between the WPF UI and the untyped `System.Data` stuff. Keep in mind that WinRT (for example) does NOT have `System.Data` stuff. Therefore you should get used NOT to use it. Nowadays no serious application goes without at least a small amount of ORM. Even if you do it yourself by manually mapping the `System.Data` stuff to classes serverside.

Comment: NO ONE does old-style ADO.Net stuff these days. It's pretty much deprecated in favor of ORMs such as Entity Framework.

Comment: Thank you for your input. In VB6 the display data of a ListBox could be accessed using ListBox1.List(ListBox1.SelectedIndex), and the (optional) underlying IDs could be accessed using ListBox1.ItemData(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) etc assuming ListBox1 was suitably populated beforehand. I need to confirm whether a similar simplicity exists in wpf.net. If it doesn't I will investigate other technologies... So near and yet so far!

Comment: you can use ListBox.SelectedItems, however my point still stands. WPF is not VB6 (not even near) and requires a really different mindset to work with. WPF does not care what you want or what your ways are. In order to use WPF you have to do it "the WPF way". Otherwise you will fail miserably. That's my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    MsgBox(ListBox1.SelectedItems(i).Row.ItemArray(0))
Next
```

Not as simple as VB6, but that can be expected as wpf ListItems can contain many controls.